# Geometric Series

Tags: recursion, recurrence

Solving a recurrence relation: 
T(n) = qT(n/2) + cn where q is a const > 2

Ive got it to T(n) <= cn * sum{0, log_2(n) - 1} (q/2)^i

I'm trying to use geometric series to calculate this: a = 1, r = q/2, n = log_2(n)

I get

1) S = (1-r^(log_2(n)) / (1 - r) and somehow this ends up as

2) S = (r^log_2(n) - 1) / (r - 1) according to a textbook

Im confused as to how they get from 1) to 2), any explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: what number do you need to multiply the denominator of 1) by to get the denominator of 2)? And what do you get by multiplying the numerator of 1) by this number?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog wow i feel like an idiot lol thank you